# Python GUI line break

Tags: python, user-interface, button

I have a GUI application in Python that has two buttons both aligned to the left side, the code looks like this:

```
Button(root, text="blah").pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text="blah").pack(side=LEFT)
```

This code works great, but in the GUI how would you put these two buttons on different lines?

Comment: Which GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(assuming you're using Tkinter) I think you'd just pack it...

e.g.

```
Button(root,text="blah").pack()
```

Note that generally, it is better practice to make the button and then pack it on separate lines.

This sort of geometry can also be accomplished with grid.

```
b1=Button(root,text="blah")
b2=Button(root,text="blah")
b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
b2.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

However, you shouldn't mix grid and pack geometry manager...(pick one and stick with it)

Comment: Generally, I prefer the grid geometry manager, but it's a matter of preference which you choose...

Comment: Is  there any way to make the columns smaller

Comment: @user1368903 Generally the columns are as big as they need to be to fit the widgets ... So to make the columns skinnier, you need to make your widgets skinnier.  Most widgets have a "width" attribute that you can pass to the constructor (or "height" if you're looking to make it shorter)...

Comment: @mglison This is helpful advice, but i have a widget thats about 200 pixels across and when i put a button in column one it does the same as packing it with the side set to left, and there is no way to put anything on the far right of the widget.